# Method streamDownload does not exist

Tags: laravel, pdf-generation

I'm trying to download a file with laravel, but I got this error!

```
exception:  "BadMethodCallException"
file "C:\Users\dev\gaaho\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable.php"
line 96
message : "Method streamDownload does not exist."
```

this is what i have in my controller

```
return response()->streamDownload(function () {
    echo GitHub::api('repo')
                ->contents()
                ->readme('laravel', 'laravel')['contents'];
}, 'laravel-readme.md');
```

Please help! I'm using laravel 5.5

Comment: The function `streamDownload` is a new feature in `5.6`.

Comment: then how to make it aviable in 5.5 ?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$name = 'laravel-readme.md';
$headers = [
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename='. $name,
];
return response()->stream(function() {
    echo GitHub::api('repo')
                ->contents()
                ->readme('laravel', 'laravel')['contents'];
}, 200, $headers);
```

See if that works. You're basically just manually setting the headers.

Comment: Thank @Mark, but i got this error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse::header()

Comment: Try removing the ``$headers`` argument from the ``stream`` function and put ``response()->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='. $name);`` before you return your response.

Comment: Glad to help - hope that answers your question.